# Arranging div elements using css floats

Tags: html, css

I have the following `div`elements that are generated randomly so I can't make changes to a single `div` element.Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/2/ .But I need a particular change. I want the space occupied by the first and the fourth posts to be occupied by a single post.i.e the first image needs to be twice the size of the rest.In total five images will be rendered then. I've tried doing it but can't figure out how.

html

```
<div class="relatedposts">
 <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
        <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
         <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
         <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
         <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
         <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
        <h3 class="justin-cover">This one clearly has too many lines that do not fit</h3>
 </div>
```

css

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}



.relatedposts {
display:table; 
width:1024px;font-size: 0;
/* fix inline gap */
margin: 0 auto;}



.relatedthumb {
float: left;
margin-left:5px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.relatedthumb img {
text-align:center;
}
.justin-cover {
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 500;
/* height: 30%; */
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
padding: 10px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in CSS :

```
.relatedthumb:first-child img {
    height: 300px;   /* with your desire size */
    width:300px;     /* with your desire size */
}
```

Here, the `:first-child` will target the first element only.

Comment: I wanted to show the first post as twice the size and the remaining four as they were earlier

Answer (score 0):

as i figure out you need those div to represent differently according to the number.

an example : the first image red border and the fourth blue border

you can use jquery to solve this

you can set two class

```
class="relatedthumb special"
```

for the div you want to make it special

```
$(".specail").css("border","red")
```

and if it not the solution you search please explain your problem little more

or you can do it with out a class :

```
var count = 0;

$( "#relatedthumb " ).each(function( i ) {
    if(count%4 == 0)
    {
       this.style.width= "400";
       this.style.height= "400";
     }
     count++;
  });
```

so first image in every iterate will be with size 400*400

Comment: I could use that but the problem is that all these are being randomly generated with the same class name.I want one of the images to be 400px/400px and four images to be next to it of 200px/200px dimension arranged it square formation

Comment: wish image you want it to be the 400px\400px ?

Comment: have you edited the js fiddle code because I can't see any changes here.Could you give me a link to the js fiddle edit

Comment: no i am sorry i was writing it now check the post again

Comment: no I see the edit but the edit is not making any difference.see http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/5/

Comment: you should add the code inside $(document).ready(function() { //code here });

and include the jquery library you can download it from :http://jquery.com/